# How to select all but $(this) in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, radio-button

```
$(".dist_radio").click(function() {
        $(this).attr("class", "dist_radio dist_on");
        if (!$(this)) {
            $(".dist_on").attr("class", "dist_radio");
        }


        console.log($(this).attr("class"));
    });
```

I'm using this code to style radio buttons and it sort of works apart from the fact that when I click on another button, the rest don't get `dist_on` class removed. Can you please tell me what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `.not` method:

```
$(".dist_radio").not(this).attr("class", "dist_radio");
```

But for your logic, you could just do like below (use `addClass`/`removeClass` instead of changing the `class` attribute directly):

```
$(".dist_radio").click(function() {
    $(".dist_radio").removeClass('dist_on');
    $(this).addClass('dist_on');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)**:

> Remove elements from the set of matched elements.

```
$(".dist_radio").click(function () {
    $(this).attr("class", "dist_radio dist_on");
    $(".dist_on").not(this).attr("class", "dist_radio");
    console.log($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

or better using **[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)** and **[.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)** to make your code clearer:

```
$(".dist_radio").click(function () {
    $(".dist_radio").removeClass("dist_on");
    $(this).addClass("dist_on");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/) function to exclude the element from the selected set. Passing this to `.not()` will exclude the current object. You do not need `if` here to exclude it.

```
 $(".dist_on").not(this).attr("class", "dist_radio");
```

> **[.not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/):** Remove elements from the set of matched elements.

Your code would be

```
$(".dist_radio").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("class", "dist_radio dist_on");
    $(".dist_on").not(this).attr("class", "dist_radio");
});
```